# Error al crear nueva instancia de una clase en Java

Tags: java

tengo dos archivos con los siguientes nombres: `Main.java` y `Animal.java` con el siguiente contenido

```
# Animal.java

package main;

public class Animal {
private int edad;
private float peso;

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public int getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(int peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public String toString() {
    return "My age is " + this.getEdad() + "and " + this.getPeso();
}

}
```

Main.java

```
package main;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal test = new Animal();

    test.setEdad(10);
    test.setPeso(120f);

    System.out.println(test);
}
 }
```

Al intentar compilar me salta el siguiente error

> Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol Animal test = new Animal();

Los archivos se encuentran en el mismo nivel

`abc
  | Main.java
  | Animal.java`

Comment: Corregí los errores de tu código, lo probé y funcionó. El problema radica que las clases `Main.java` y `Animal.java` deben encontrarse adentro del paquete `main`, de lo contrario, el compilador dará error de compilación porque en ningún momento encuentra esos archivos en el `package main`. Si lo compilas manualmente: `javac main/Main.java` y posteriormente lo ejecutas: `java main/Main`, debería de darte el resultado esperado.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Gracias, me funciono, si gustas puedes agregarla a respuesta para obtener puntos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol Animal test = new Animal();

El error se debe porque las clases `Main.java` y `Animal.java` deben encontrarse adentro del paquete `main`, de lo contrario, el compilador dará error de compilación porque en ningún momento encuentra esos archivos en el `package main`. Si lo compilas manualmente: `javac main/Main.java` y posteriormente lo ejecutas: `java main/Main`, debería de darte el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores tambien en la clase con respecto a la declaración y Getters y Setters.

He realizado estas modificaciones:

Tu variable Peso la puse como Float en Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    private int edad;
    private float peso;

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(float peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public String toString() {
    return "My age is " + this.getEdad() + "and " + this.getPeso();
}

}
```

Y en tu Main debes poner `test.setEdad` y no `yagua.setEdad` porque la variable de tu Objeto se llama `test`

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal test = new Animal();

    test.setEdad(10);
    test.setPeso(120f);

    System.out.println(test);
 }
```

De esta forma tu programa funcionará.

Comment: Me sigue saltando el error `Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
 Animal test = new Animal();
 ^
  symbol:   class Animal
  location: class Main
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
 Animal test = new Animal();
                   ^
  symbol:   class Animal
  location: class Main
2 errors
`

Comment: A pesar que el código del OP tiene errores, esto no soluciona el problema.

Answer (score -1):

solo cambia estos métodos, la variable "peso" la declaraste de tipo "float"

```
public float getPeso() {
    return  peso;
}

public void setPeso(float peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
```

Comment: No me funciono, me sigue dando el mismo error, gracias

Comment: E probado el código y me ha funcionado

Comment: Animal test = null;   test = new Animal();

Comment: No se porque no me funciona, aqui mi version `openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
`